# Using database query results instead of displaying in datagrid

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am using C# to create a Silverlight 4 application.

I am trying to do the following:

```
        MapNode endNode = null;

        if (keyword != null && keyword != "")
        {
            EntityQuery<NodeIDProj> res = CampusQueries.getNodeIDByNameQuery(keyword);

            var queryres = CampusQueries.Load<NodeIDProj>(res, (items) =>
            {
                foreach (var item in items.Entities)
                {
                    MapNode n = mapHelp.getNodeByID(item.NodeID);

                    if (n != null)
                    {
                        endNode = n;
                        TrackAnimation();

                    }
                }

            }, true);
         }
```

However, after this point, my variable endNode is still null. TrackAnimation() works as though endNode has a valid value, but outside of the Load statement, endNode is back to null.

I know that I am lacking in understanding of how this works, and I would really appreciate an help given.

What I am trying to do, is query my database and I want to use those results in other methods rather than displaying them in a datagrid.

I want endNode to have value which I can use in other methods.

Please help me to figure out a way to do this, thank you!

EDIT:

Thank you, SLaks

Can I do something like:

MapNode endNode = null;

```
    if (keyword != null && keyword != "")
    {
        EntityQuery<NodeIDProj> res = CampusQueries.getNodeIDByNameQuery(keyword);

        var queryres = CampusQueries.Load<NodeIDProj>(res, (items) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in items.Entities)
            {
                MapNode n = mapHelp.getNodeByID(item.NodeID);

                if (n != null)
                {
                    endNode = n;
                    TrackAnimation();

                }
            }

        }, true);
     }
 queryres.Completed += new EventHandler(queryres_Completed);




void queryres_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //stuff
}
```

If so, how can I get access to the endNode variable, as it is declared within another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Load` method is probably asynchronous, meaning that the callback happens some time after the rest of your code runs.

You can only use the result after you actually receive it.

Comment: @Valerie: Only inside the callback, which will run after the method itself finishes.

Comment: thanks! I have another question to post, hope you are still around :)